# Draw influence of dots in network

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have run into a somewhat annoying problem which is difficult to explain without knowing the proper vocabulary, but the following two images should explain what I'm looking for.

I have a network of connected dots. Each dot has a color property.

[Dot Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYpjL.png)

Each dot in the network represents a location which, for the lack of a better term, is "owned" by the respective color. I would now like to properly showcase the influence each owned dot has on its vicinity, i.e. the colors "territory", by generating something akin to this:

[Colored Dot Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GA5vn.png)

I cannot see a trivial solution to this. The most probable solution I can see is to generate a plane, pass information about each dot to an appropriate shader and use that to compute the texture of the plane. Unlike this example however, there are not just 10 dots, but likely somewhere between 1000-2000.

To pose some more specific questions:

1) Could a shader handle the amount of dots (1000+)?

2) I am not sure what kind of algorithm the shader would have to have in order to achieve the right result. Iterating through all dots and comparing them to all remaining dots and generating some sort of weight seems.. suboptimal. My background being in physics, the first instinct is something that generates something akin to a Wigner-seitz cell. (I would provide a link to an image explaining what I mean, but it appears I can only post 2 links with a fresh account. A quick google image search should however have plenty of good results)

3) And the most obvious one: Is there a trivial solution I'm missing?

Comment: Are the dots ever going to move or alter their influence radius? If not, it may be more performant to generate a polygon of influence for each dot, relative to its immediate neighbors, and update each polygon's color as needed.

Comment: @rutter They do not move relative to eachother, nor will their connections ever change. Generating a polygon per dot is not something I have considered before. Although in retrospect, my first instinct with the Wigner-seitz cell would be exactly that, so maybe it does have merit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would do, create an array of all dots and their locations, let's talk about this like you will run this in fullscreen in unity, then create a new array that holds the position of all dots, but instead of world position we want position in pixels. Now here is that part in code:

```
Transform[] dots;
Vector3[] position; //Vector2 is more appropriate because of 2D space but most of the Unity functions support only Vector3

void Awake(){
    for(int i =0; i < dots.Length; i++)
        position[i] = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(dots[i].position);
}
```

Now we have position of all dots on screen, next thing would be creating actual texture.

```
Texture2D outTex = new Texture2D (Screen.height, Screen.width, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
```

Now we should iterate through each pixel on this Texture and create specific formula to determine what color should that pixel be.

Add another array variable of type Color32, which would define color for each dot (by who is it "owned").

```
int h = outTex.height;
int w = outTex.width;
for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
        //Formula for determining color is right here, here is my suggestion 
        //(the most simplest one), check the color of each dot and based on the distance 
        //between this pixel and dot's position determine how much influence that dot
        //has on this pixel, here is how it goes
        float red = 0;
        float green = 0;
        float blue = 0;
        float divider = 0;
        for(int c = 0; c < dots.Length; c++){
            float curDist = Vector3.Distance(dots[c].position, new Vector3(j, i ,0);
            curDist = 1f/(curDist+1f);
            red += dotColors[c].r * curDist;
            green += dotColors[c].g * curDist;
            blue += dotColors[c].b * curDist;
            divider++;
        }
        outTex.SetPixel (j , i, new Color32(red/divider, green/divider, blue/divider, 255);    
    }
outTex.Apply();
```

And the last part would be add some sprite that has the size of the whole screen and apply this texture to it.

All of this is just to give you basic idea of how would you go about to solve it, all of this code is untested so you will prolly find some errors in it, but I leave that work to you. If you find any problems put a comment here and I will respond, I am more than willing to help you since you introduced a interesting question. This all reminds me of rendering white 2D texture with light sources of different colors in front of it (this is your dots), so try finding online how people are writing a scripts for 2D light rendering, you will prolly find some interesting and useful things there.

Comment: I've taken your approach and changed it a bit so instead of blending the colors together, it uses the color of whatever Dot is closest and it does in fact produce the exact result I'm looking for, however... there are 2000 dots in the average-case scenario with the texture needing to be a rather high resolution for the result to look acceptable. Even a 3k * 3k texture doesn't look great. With that amount of data, the algorithm takes enough for me to cook dinner in the meantime. I could cache the result, however it is one of the few things that is guaranteed to change over time

Comment: Can you send me produced image or screenshot? I am really interested to see how it looks but I don't have time to set it all up now :) The problem why it takes so long is because "SetPixel" is very slow and ineffective, because each time you call it takes a whole bunch of memory and than deletes all of it just to set color of one pixel, try using "SetPixels" http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixels.html

Comment: [Here](http://imgur.com/p8YEpHq) is how it looks currently. I assigned a random color to each dot just to test, but it should look exactly the way I need it to once each dot has the appropriate color. I'll give SetPixels a try now and compare the time it takes compared to SetPixel

Comment: Switching form SetPixel to SetPixels has not sped up things a lot. I suspect that the bottleneck is not setting the pixels, but iterating through all the dots for every pixel as well as Vector3.Distance calls.. I can't think of any way to reduce the number of checks needed

Comment: Take in mind that you call Vector3.Distance for each pixel by the number of how many dots you have, so let's say you are running this on full HD resolution, number of calls is equal to 1680*1050*2000, and that is 3 and half BILLION times and distance is calculated by pythagorean, which requires square root and that is very expensive, now the good thing is that we don't need that square root because we are just comparing distances, and if square of one distance is larger than square of another distance then the first distance is larger, no point for calculating roots and then compering them.

Comment: Math says that if x^2 > y^2 then we know that x > y, so replace the line that calculates the distance to this 
float curDist = (dots[c].position.x - j)^2 + (dots[c].position.y - i)^2;

Comment: Googling around a bit, it says that Unity's Vector3.Distance call is already very optimized to the point where I expect no additional performance gain from comparing the square of the distance as you are suggesting. I'll try it nontheless

Comment: Dude... Unity's Vector3.Distance uses square root, my formula doesn't, read this http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-sqrMagnitude.html

Comment: I have found one approach that seems to work excellently: Instead of iterating through all dots, I can use Physics.OverlapSphere to test for nearby Colliders, which all the dots conveniently already have! Where iterating through all dots took ~15 seconds, this approach takes 0.1 seconds with a texture of equal size. I consider this to be good enough for my purposes and the problem solved. Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Hmm interesting aay to do it, glad it works and glad I helped.